# C : Validation in strptime

Tags: c, validation, strptime

strptime() function in C fails to detect invalid dates. Ex: 2011-02-31 , 2011-04-31.
Is there any other function or workaround to this problem

Comment: I am looking out for something that would give me an indication as to which part of the date is invalid. Just like how strptime() returns the pointer to the last valid character parsed. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `mktime` to normalize your structure after using `strptime`.

```
struct tm ltm = {0};
char buf[] = "2011-02-31";
puts(buf);
strptime(buf, "%Y-%m-%d", &ltm);
mktime(&ltm);
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d", &ltm);
puts(buf);
```

The example above will produce the output below:

```
2011-02-31
2011-03-03
```

If the strings before and after `mktime` do not match, then you know the input string was not a valid date.

If you need to know which field was invalid, you can save a copy of the `ltm` structure before calling `mktime`. Then, you can examine if the day (`tm_mday`), month (`tm_mon`), or year (`tm_year`) was the one in the invalid format. For `tm_mon`, `0` is January, and `11` is December. For `tm_year`, it is the number of years since `1900`. Remember to account for leap year when validating the day of the month for February.

Comment: Hmmm... then I have to recompare and check if the date before normalize is the same as the date after normalize? Its a solution.. yes, but I was looking out for something that would give me an indication that the date is invalid. Just like how strptime() returns the pointer to the last valid character parsed

Comment: That is one way to do it. It's easier that way than to manually dig through the `tm` structure to see if all the fields are right.

Comment: @AndyStowAway: I updated the answer with how to go about doing the validation. Regards

Comment: user315052: Hmmmm, how about we make two `tm` structures. One with the invalid date (before we normalize) and then another one after normalize. Then can we compare both the structures and see where the mismatch has occured ?? Any issues in this solution?

Comment: @AndyStowAway: That is fine. But, I think a strcmp will tell you the same thing. Basically, if the strings are different, it was the `tm_mday` field that was wrong. So, you probably should just check that field first.

Comment: I think that the only way to make this work is to compare the two `tm` structures. Imagine the case where `char buf[] = "2011-2-28"`. `strftime()` output would give you `2011-02-28` and `strcmp` would wrongly declare the input date as invalid

Comment: @lano1106: There is an assumption that the input is in the same format as the output. Comparing `struct tm`s is mentioned in the last paragraph.

Comment: On the other hand if the variable is out of range e.g. for *`%M`* you have 60 it seems to be set to 0 (iirc it's not modulo but it's been a very very long day and I’m beyond done so can't check). This of course can complicate matters depending on the goal in mind.