# How to scan specific string format in C?

Tags: c, string, format

I have an assignment where I have to communicate with SQL database through C, and while I am able to do that fine, if specific string format is not used, the data does not get put into the database.

To make it short, I am scanning in one string (date of birth) and database expects format "years-months-days" in that specific format, but I am unable to figure out how to check if the string is indeed in that format. So for example, it expects "1995-11-23".

Any help is very welcome. Thanks!

```
printf("What is the date of brith you would like to input?\n");
fgets(birth_date, 255, stdin);
```

Comment: Why don't you start by telling the user the format you expect (`yyyy-mm-dd`) in your prompt?

Comment: @KenWhite I would, but this is a school related task, and their whole point is to try to break my code every way possible. The code as a whole is a lot bigger and I've taken different precautions to not break the code, but this is one of the problems I was unable to figure out.

Comment: myabe you can get the database to tell you the date is wrong, (but maybe you're usuing mysql or something worse,)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `strptime` to parse the time, and then a [combination of `mktime` and `strftime` to validate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11428118/8767209) the date is actually valid.

Consider the following code:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char birth_date[12], *p, *state="invalid";
    struct tm tv = {0};
    fprintf(stdout, "Enter date: yyyy-mm-dd: ");
    if (fgets(birth_date, sizeof(birth_date), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        if ((p = strchr(birth_date, '\n')) != NULL)
            *p = 0;  /* Remove the newline left by fgets */

        if ((p = strptime(birth_date, "%Y-%m-%d", &tv)) != NULL)
        {
            char b[12];
            mktime(&tv); 
            if ((strftime(b, sizeof(b), "%Y-%m-%d", &tv) > 0) &&
                 strcmp(b, birth_date) == 0)
            {
                state = "valid";
            }
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "Date %s is %s\n", birth_date, state);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Yields:

```
 Enter date: yyyy-mm-dd: 2019-05-11
 Date 2019-05-11 is valid

 Enter date: yyyy-mm-dd: foo
 Date foo is invalid

 Enter date: yyyy-mm-dd: 2018-02-29
 Date 2018-02-29 is invalid

 Enter date: yyyy-mm-dd: 2016-02-29
 Date 2016-02-29 is valid
```

Comparing `birth_date` against the result of `strftime` also has the side effect of disallowing extra characters in `birth_date` that were not converted to a date.  For instance, if the user inputted `2019-05-11`(with a space at the end), this date would be rejected as invalid.

Comment: The idiom `birth_date[strspn(birth_date, "\n")] = '\0';` avoids a visible condition in your code and safely zaps the newline if present, or overwrites the null byte at the end of the string if not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can you clarify please? I don't understand the problem you are addressing. It looks like that line will set birth_date[0] = 0 on valid input.

Comment: I mistyped `strcspn()` — my bad, and sorry!  The advantage of using `strcspn()` instead of `strchr()` is that only one line of code is needed to zap the newline, instead of two.  That's all.  (And people concerned about speed worry about conditionals, and the one liner doesn't show any conditional in the code, but they're buried in the function instead, so there are conditions — hence my 'visible condition' qualifier.)