# user entered date formatted using strftime() in c++

Tags: c++

so i want to format a user entered date (for example "10/12/2003" or "10-12-2003") and turn it into December 10 2003, I already know how to use strftime() and have built this program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int Fdate(string date){

  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  char buffer [80];

  time (&rawtime);
  timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

  strftime (buffer,80,"Today is %B %d, %Y.",timeinfo);
  puts (buffer);

  return 0;
}


int main(){
  string date = "10/12/2003";
  Fdate(date);
}
```

so now I want the date that is being formatted to be entered by the user, any ideas??

Comment: Something like `std::cin >> date;` maybe?

Comment: After you read a string just call `strptime` to create a time from it. You may need to call mktime to normalise the results (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428014/c-validation-in-strptime)